# Удаление картинок из кэша браузера после их отображения

Tags: кэширование, javascript, php

Как сделать, чтобы изображения не накапливались в памяти браузера, т.е. после отображения удалялись (php или javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

В адресе каждого изображения добавьте случайное число в виде get-параметра. Чтобы было что-то вида:

`<img src="image.jpg?r=15730494">`

Побочный эффект: траффик резко возрастет.

Comment: Так будет куча одинаковых картинок в кэше и удаляться они будут так же как и все остальное, то есть не сразу...

Comment: Большое спасибо у меня была проблема с заменой картинки на другую с тем же адресом. Ваше решение оказалось идеальным.

Answer (score 1):

Если картинки отдаются через php, то добавьте им заголовок:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше это делать средствами веб-сервера, но раз вопрос предлагает только JS или PHP, то так:

«Секретные» картинки следует выдавать не напрямую, а через PHP скрипт, который их отдаст с дополнительными заголовками, запрещающими кэширование. Например, вместо

```
<image src="trollface.jpg" width=.. height=.. alt=.. >
```

Будет:

```
<image src="xxx.php?src=trollface.jpg" width=.. height=.. alt=.. >
```

А внутри этот php будет определять MIME тип запрошенной картинки, и выводить её содержание:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // дата в прошлом

// Получить имя запрашиваемого файла
$filename = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'src', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// Узнать расширение файла
$ext = strtolower( pathinfo( $fullPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
switch ($ext) {
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
// считать и выдать в ответ содержание файла как есть
readfile( $filename);
```

В этом примере пропущены некоторые моменты - напр. проверка того, что файл существует, его размера, и выдача размера в заголовке `Content-Length`, а также некоторые вопросы безопасности. Просто скопировать и использовать код нельзя, увы.

Comment: имхо, статику нестатично отдавать сама по себе странная задача. а для картинок типа капчи и так генерация идет в коде, т.е. статических файлов для них не бывает...

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к моему ответу?

Comment: Это имеет отношение к примеру - про то, что берем статичную картинку и отдаем ее с изменением заголовков. Если ТС имел в виду статичные картинки, то для них нужно править заголовки в апачах и проч. А если динамические, то пример не в тему.

Comment: @Yura А что я написал в первой же строке про веб сервер? Исходил из 1-го варианта гадания. Для 2-го варианта пригодятся строки кода с заголовками — не всегда динамические картинки догадываются вызывать с GET-параметрами.

Answer (score 0):

(HardMode) Скрипт или что либо похожее на то, что ты хочешь видеть. (EasyMode) Просто сводишь кэш браузера к минимуму и наслаждаешься тем как при каждом обновлении твои фото подгружаются заново (но при этом прогруженое в реальном времени аудио и видео будет работать, а после обновления нет!) (GoogleMode) Можно поискать плагины для браузера которые будут разрешать грузить в кэш по щелчку и галочке.